# Projectile indexes my home directory, how do I stop it from doing that?

Tags: projectile

Since I updated the whole of my emacs third party packages projectile has started to see my home folder (which emacs opens in) as a projectile project.

[image: Screenshot of helm-projectile showing the home folder as projectile project]

There is no `.projectile` file in my home folder, neither is my home folder under version control.

```
marcus@mri-tp:~ >>> cat ~/.projectile
cat: /home/marcus/.projectile: No such file or directory
```

My home folder is also not in my `projectile-bookmarks.eld`:

```
("~/.emacs.d/" "~/projects/pwb-ss15/" "~/projects/fhw-symmrecog/" "~/fhw/ss15/dbassistenz/" "~/projects/dsa-compendium/" "~/.zprezto/" "~/projects/pwb-ws13/" "~/fhw/ss15/db/" "~/fhw/ss15/ps2_00/" "~/projects/jekyll-school/" "~/projects/webIsoRogue/" "~/projects/spacerace/" "~/projects/marcusriemer.de/")
```

I am however using projectile together with `helm` and `ecb`. To sync the `ecb` file tree I use the snippet from [the emacs wiki: ecb + projectile](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Projectile):

```
(defvar default-ecb-source-path ())

(add-hook 'ecb-basic-buffer-sync-hook
                (lambda ()
                        (when (functionp 'projectile-get-project-directories)
                        (when (projectile-project-p)
                                (dolist (path-dir (projectile-get-project-directories))
                                (unless (member (list path-dir path-dir) default-ecb-source-path)
                                        (push (list path-dir path-dir) default-ecb-source-path)
                                        (customize-set-variable 'ecb-source-path default-ecb-source-path)
                                        ))))))
```

As far as I can tell I have not set `projectile-require-project-root(nil)`:

```
marcus@mri-tp:~/.emacs.d >>> find . -iname "*.el" | xargs grep "projectile-require-project-root"
./elpa/helm-projectile-20150610.253/helm-projectile.el:  (let ((projectile-require-project-root nil))
./elpa/helm-projectile-20150610.253/helm-projectile.el:  (let* ((projectile-require-project-root nil)
./elpa/helm-projectile-20150610.253/helm-projectile.el:                (let ((projectile-require-project-root nil))
./elpa/projectile-20150610.2247/projectile.el:(defcustom projectile-require-project-root t
./elpa/projectile-20150610.2247/projectile.el:        (if projectile-require-project-root
./elpa/projectile-20150610.2247/projectile.el:        (projectile-require-project-root nil))
./elpa/projectile-20150610.2247/projectile.el:  (let ((projectile-require-project-root nil))
```

Does anyone have an idea why projectile started to index my home directory? And how can I tell it to ignore my home folder once and for all?

Comment: Do you have `projectile-require-project-root` set to `nil`?

Comment: If you want to delete it, you can press `TAB` to switch to action menu, then narrow to `Delete project` action.

Comment: I have updated the question, as far as I can tell I do net set `projectile-require-project-root` myself. Deleting the project didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, this was dumb ... I had an empty `Makefile` sitting in my home directory. And because `Projectile Project Root Files Top Down Recurring` tells Projectile to recognize a `Makefile` as project root my home folder got picked up.

Just in case anybody has a similar problem in the future: If projectile picks up unwanted folders try to disable automatic project detection as a whole and see what happens. You can do that by using `M-x customize RET projectile RET` and setting `Projectile Project Root Files Functions` to an empty list. I figured out my problem after doing this **and** manually deleting the incorrect projectile bookmark.